# Flash/AS3: Monitor "inner" (Loader) flash network activity

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a SWF AS3 file which loads up an external swf using standard AS3 Loader.

The inner SWF (the one I load from my swf) makes several http network calls, and I would like to monitor them (e.g. be able to grab the URL of the requests being made), from my SWF (same AS3 code that loaded this inner SWF).

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score -1):

You need a HTTP proxy to capture the network traffic. There are many tools available that do this.

For the lowest level in capturing TCP packets, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is the best but overkill for a lot of people for 'simple' http monitoring.

For a higher level view of the http traffic, there are various tools that work well with Flash, [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) has built in AMF decoding, etc.. for Flash and it is cross-platform. [Fidder](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is a great Window's based proxy, but there are many others...

What one you choice is really based upon your needs and then factoring in choice of platform, open source or not, freeware or pay version...

Comment: Thanks. I am well aware of HTTP proxies/sniffers, but as I wrote in my question, I am looking to do this from my SWF (AS3). So I need something like the tools that you have mentioned as an AS3 lib.

Comment: Ah, I do not know of an existing lib, but two ways then. If an Air app you can create your own proxy via the flash.net.ServerSocket if you have admin access to create sockets below 1024, do not believe a sandbox'd Flash swf can do that even with a socket policy file. The other way would be if the inner swf is loaded in 'your' application domain, you can create proxy classes that you wish to 'control/monitor', i.e. just like the preloader does with RSLs. Normally this would be to add new classes/singletons/statics for the child swf have access to, but you can proxy an class that way.